# Javascript Synchronous Console Prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronous

I am trying to get started in Javascript by making a tic tac toe game on the console. This would require a while loop that takes in moves from the user.

This has proven to be much harder than I expected. Is there an easy way that I am missing.

I have tried using async.whilst, and sync-prompt. The former just sent me into an endless loop and the latter had errors when I tried using npm install to download it. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: If you're working with IO, I think it's better to start learning asynchronous right from scratch. Use a recursive approach instead of a loop, and it'll be a waltz.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: When designing a game, even a simple tic-tac-toe game, you need to first identify the sequence of steps that each 'iteration' of the game requires, as well as the end conditions and possible states. Take that, turn it into a loop or recursive function.

Comment: I would also suggest to get used with async right from the beginning. For your case [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) will be helpfull.

Comment: node.js is an event-driven environment and that's how apps should work.  You should respond to events to drive your app, not use a loop to wait on events.

Comment: Okay, I am finally starting to understand all of this. I come from Java and C++, so it's not natural at all to think recursively from the beginning. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a library. Just use node's built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

Here's their example:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log('Thank you for your valuable feedback:', answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: `readline` functions are is asynchronous, so this doesn't work. Perhaps it wasn't at the time of this answer?

Comment: It works on node v6.11 for me. Do read the code again, handling of the input happens in the callback so it's async.

Comment: To my understanding, cbrauns is asking for a synchronous way to ask for input using a while loop. If we add `console.log("hi")` below your code, that will print before the user is prompted for an input. The only way for him to create his game using `readline` is to use recursion within his callback rather than use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [prompt-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync). It's not the same as the one you tried. In any case, if for some reason the npm installation fails, you can always grab the source code from [its github page](https://github.com/0x00A/prompt-sync)

It's not a perfect solution though, at least for me, as it doesn't catch accented characters or the spanish ñ character on the answer.

Anyways, this doesn't seem an easy task to do on node.

UPDATE: I found another way that works, at least for my purposes, since node 8, by using async and await combined with an IIFE:

```
(async function() {
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,   
        output: process.stdout 
    });  

    function prompt(message) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            rl.question(message, (answer) => {
                resolve(answer);
            });
        }); 
    }  

    var answer = await prompt("What do you have to say? ");
    console.log("\nYou answered: \n" + answer);
    rl.close(); 
})();
```